# "Значит" - союз или вводное слово?

Tags: пунктуация

Является ли здесь "значит" вводным словом (и тогда запятые нужны с двух сторон) или союзом?

Это значит, что мы так и не избавились от тяги к лукавым цифрам и значит они опять кому-то нужны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Значит - в значении "означает", т.е. это глагол, сказуемое. "Это значит (означает), что..." -сложноподчинённое предложение с придаточным изъяснительным.

Второе "значит" может быть как вводным словом (Это значит, что мы так и не избавились от тяги к лукавым цифрам и, значит, они опять кому-то нужны), так и повтором сказуемого (Это значит, что мы так и не избавились от тяги к лукавым цифрам, и значит, они опять кому-то нужны).Это значит... и значит (это означает ...и означает) - два сказуемых. Зависит от автора, какой смысл вкладывает. Вводное, по-моему, больше подходит.